# Includes doesn't work with LinqKit AsExpandable

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.0, linqkit

I'm trying to use `LinqKit` `AsExpandable` in my `EfCore2.0` project and I am running into this problem where the `Includes` doesn't work.

In attempting to debug this I have downloaded the `LinqKit` source from github and have replaced the `Nuget` references in my project with Project references.

When debugging with the `LinqKit` project, I noticed that the my call to `Include` wasn't hitting a breakpoint I set on `ExpandableQueryOfClass<T>.Include`.

I did some further testing and noticed the breakpoint *is* hit if I first cast to `ExpandableQueryOfClass` (this is an internal class in `LinqKit` which I made public, so I can't do the cast if I'm referencing the `Nuget` package).

Is this a bug in `LinqKit` or am I doing something wrong?

Here is my test code.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using Internal.DAL.Db;
using Internal.Models.Customer;

using LinqKit; // Referencing LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
using Xunit;

namespace Internal.EntityFramework.Tests
{
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext> _ctxBuilder =>
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>().UseSqlServer(Connection.String);

        [Fact]
        public async Task SuccessTest()
        {
            using (var ctx = new DataContext(_ctxBuilder.Options))
            {
                var query = 
                    (
                        // this cast is the only difference between the methods
                        (ExpandableQueryOfClass<Order>)
                        ctx.Orders
                        .AsExpandable()
                    )
                    .Include(r => r.Customer)
                    .Take(500);

                var responses = await query.ToListAsync();

                // this succeeds
                Assert.All(responses, r => Assert.NotNull(r.Customer));
            }
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task FailTest()
        {
            using (var ctx = new DataContext(_ctxBuilder.Options))
            {
                var query = ctx.Orders
                    .AsExpandable()
                    .Include(r => r.Customer)
                    .Take(500);

                var responses = await query.ToListAsync();

                // this fails
                Assert.All(responses, r => Assert.NotNull(r.Customer));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit `2018-05-15`: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/issues/14) on the LinqKit github repository.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is LINQKit or EF Core fault (definitely it's not yours).

For sure it's caused by the EF Core `Include` / `ThenInclude` [implementations](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/dev/src/EFCore/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs#L2222) which all include a check for `source.Provider is EntityQueryProvider` and do nothing in case it's `false`.

I'm not sure what's the idea of EF Core designers - probably custom query providers to inherit from `EntityQueryProvider`, but at the same time the class is part of the infrastructure and marked as not supposed to be used.

I also have no idea how LINQKit is planning to address it, but as you noticed the current implementation definitely is broken/not working. At the moment it looks to me more like a WIP.

The only workaround I see at this time is to apply `AsExpandable()` after includes.